# How can I provide different models in support of a/b testing with ML Kit?

Tags: firebase-mlkit

How can I provide different models in support of a/b testing with ML Kit?

I'm looking at the [implementation path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/use-custom-models?authuser=0#implementation_path) for ML Kit and I'm a little concerned because I don't see any description of support for multiple models. I need to support A/B tests with my models.

My planned workflow:

1. build a "default model" that everyone can use.
2. retrain the model as input comes in from the user base. update the model on a schedule.
3. allow a/b testing for using/not using the model, and comparing different models to decide a progression.
4. users download the model, possibly converting to CoreML ?, and running it locally as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow is supported using Firebase Remote Config and A/B testing. Here is how you'd go about it:

1. [Publish](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/use-custom-models) your TFLite models in ML Kit, via the Firebase console. Give each model a unique name.
2. When loading the remote model in the app, use [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config) to dynamically switch the model name via the Firebase console instead of hardcoding the model name.
3. You can use [A/B testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing) in combination with [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config), to set a different value for the config variable (i.e. each different will be the name of the different model you have published)